# how write modular design in c# ,asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, modular

I want write project modular and write each part project can use other project.
How can I do?
Do you have tutorial or example for it?
What should I to be learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following things to achieve this.

1. Create **entity** class project to define your entities.
2. Create **repository** to interact with database in another class project.
3. Create **Service** to write business logic int another class library.
4. Now you can write your presentation layer in another asp.net project.

[image]

You should learn dependency injection, IOC principals, repository pattern, singleton to learn more about design.